# Basic openframeWorks shader programming with textures

Tags: c++, textures, glsl, shader, openframeworks

I'm currently trying to use shaders to modify my 2d images for simple stuff, mainly things like in the tutorials, and I want to implement them in my project.

The thing is, I can't use GLSL version 150 because some of our existing shaders are using another version and it's not compatible, I was just wondering if it's possible to just apply a ahder to an ofImage or something.

I've tried so far but it doesn't seem like the shader is understanding that the texture it has is an image, it just draws colors depending on the ofSetColor.

Here's some code, and the fragment and vertex shaders I'm using are kinda basic (dummy code I got, dunno if it works)

Fragment shader :

```
uniform sampler2DRect texture0;

void main()
{
    //Getting coordinates of the current pixel in texture
    vec2 pos = gl_TexCoord[0].xy;

    //Getting the pixel color from the texture texture0 in pos
    vec4 color = texture2DRect(texture0, pos);

    //Output the color of shader
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Vertex shader :

```
void main()
{
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
}
```

ofApp.cpp :

```
void ofApp::setup()
{
    ofDisableArbTex();
    ofEnableDepthTest();

    m_shader.load("shaders/shaderTest");
    m_image.loadImage("sunflower.png");
}

void ofApp::draw()
{
    m_shader.begin();
    m_image.draw(0, 0);
    m_shader.end();
}
```

So basically what I want to know is how to "pass my image" unto the shader so I can change simple things like it's color, and maybe do some basic distortion effects.

Also, I'm going to use these in a 3D project world (some sandbox).

Any tips on how to get started and maybe help me understand a bit more what I'm doing wrong would help !

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell the shader about the texture, something like

```
shader.setUniformTexture("texture0", m_image.getTextureReference(), 1 );
```

there's actually lots of shader examples in the folder OF/examples/gl/

Comment: shader.setUniformTexture("texture0", m_image.getTextureReference(), 1 );